# Enter public IP into browser and prompt for login to router?

Tags: router

I was trying to lookup my IP address in google based off what was shown in an IRC chat.

I put it in the URL input in chrome expecting to search google but instead received a login prompt for my router.

The format was like this (I changed some stuff for this post):

```
adsl-123-123-123-123.ita.att.net
```

What login could the router be asking for? I tried the admin username/pass and it wouldn't work and I don't have a VPN or anything else setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many routers cannot be reached on their public IP address from the local network. The reason for this is that most routers handle packets from the local network differently than packets from the internet.

You can ask a friend to try and reach your router from the outside if you want to check if your router can be reached. Alternatively, you can use a proxy and see if the same thing happens.

If you want to make it unreachable from the internet, you should see the manual of your router. Most likely you'll have to put the local IP address in the address bar of your browser and access the management interface from there. Here you will have the possibility to disable the management interface on the internet-facing IP address.

Comment: I'm not sure Rex did try the link: I think he inferred his reply from the description. Note that you do not need a friend to test http - there are plenty of free proxies that you can use. I frequently use proxies to test my web-site "from outside".

Comment: You're right, I misread Rex's answer. It is certainly possible to use a proxy, I would do that myself, but I think that it's easier for iliketolearn to ask a friend than to try to find and configure a proxy.

Comment: No configuration: just go to (eg) http://vectroproxy.com/ and enter your web-site address.

Comment: I was prompted to login when attempting to access via the public IP and I didn't use a proxy. I was just wondering what the long address (.ita.att.net after the IP address) meant. Any reading recommendations for a quick intro to this?

Comment: @iliketolearn that's a very common DNS naming convention for dynamic ip addresses.

Answer (score 1):

It would be looking for GUI login creds. You show att.net, so I'm assuming this is consumer-grade hardware/ATT's 2wire router? The request is coming in on port 80/http, so the router appears to have a gui service you can reach. I would assume this is for service techs to access the system.

Comment: Is it possible to hide this?

Comment: Your router should have some options to disable remote management. Usually a tick box. You have to change this by going to your router's web GUI.